# How to set environment variable based on the server/file system I log in to?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

This might be a stupid question, but I don't know where to start. At uni we have a supercomputer cluster arrangement where there are two file systems running in parallel that access different clusters. They are separate but use the same log in profile, i.e. I can ssh in with the same credentials, they use the same `bashrc` file etc.

My workflow (for better or worse) requires me to set an environment variable specifying a path to where all my code is found and output is stored. This is different depending on the cluster I log in to (since different file systems). The trouble is, if I set this environment variable in `bashrc` it will be the same on both systems.

Is there a way I can set this environment variable so that it gets a different value base on the server I log into?

Obviously I can do this manually, but I always forget and every time it ends up costing me a day or more of simulation time.

Eventually I think the intention is to migrate everything to the newer file system, but for the time being, if I want to access all the resources, I need to deal with separate file systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.bashrc` file can contain `if` statements.  You could do anything like

```
if [ "${HOSTNAME}" == "HostA" ]
then
  MYVAR=x
else
  MYVAR=y
fi
```

Another approach might be to normalize the file system by doing a bind mount (or even a symbolic link), but this approach would really depend on major details like how different they are.

Comment: Thanks! I was expecting if statements would work there, but I guess I don't know what to look for to identify the different systems. Unfortunately `HOSTNAME` is the same on both in my case

Comment: Whoops, scratch that, they are different!

Comment: If the filesystems are different, another alternative would be to set it based on whether a file or directory exists, `if [ -f /some/dir ]`